# How do I copy the active file and name it using a value in a Named range - Goolgle script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am an expert VBA programmer struggling to come to grips with Google Scripts in Google Sheets.
I'm trying to create a copy of the active file and name it from a Named Range.  I can get it to copy, but the name of the new file ends up being "Range".

Here is the code I have.

```
function SaveFileAndCopy() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rffilename = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("rfFileName");
  spreadsheet.copy(rffilename);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var rffilename = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("rfFileName");
```

#### To:

```
var rffilename = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("rfFileName").getValue();
```

- In this case, please retrieve the cell value using `getValue()`.
- Or, you might be able to also use `getDisplayValue()` instead of `getValue()`, when you want to use the display value of the cell.

#### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tanaike.  I tried your suggestions and ended up with a file named "function () { [native code] }".

Comment: @Jenny S. Thank you for replying. From your reply of `I tried your suggestions and ended up with a file named "function () { [native code] }".`, I'm worried that you might not correctly reflect my proposed answer. Because when you modify to `var rffilename = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("rfFileName").getValue`, such issue occurs. In this case, `getValue` is not run as the function. If my understanding is correct, please add `()` like `var rffilename = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("rfFileName").getValue()` and test it again. If my understanding is not correct, I apologize again.

Comment: Ah- my bad - I missed the brackets after the getValue - now it there and works perfectly.  Thanks so much.  Ha - your reply came through with the same conclusion. I really am struggling with Google scripts.  VBA is so much easier :-)

Comment: @Jenny S. Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.